# Can't seem to blit() a font in to my pygame project

Tags: python, pygame

so I was trying to show the remaining time in my pygame project, from what i've seems it does not have any kind of syntax errors or anything but it also doesn't show what I need on the screen, here's the code:

```py
import pygame
import time
import random
pygame.font.init()

#Windown Setup
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1280, 700
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong Wars")
BG = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("bggame.jpeg"), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

#Player variables
PLAYERHEIGHT = 130
PLAYERWIDTH = 20
PLAYERVELOCIT = 8

FONTE = pygame.font.SysFont("book", 30)
#functions
def bgdisplay(player1, elapsed_time):

    WIN.blit(BG, (0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, "black", player1)
    pygame.display.update()
    time_text = FONTE.render(f"Time: {round(elapsed_time)}s", 1, "white")
    WIN.blit(time_text, (10, 10))
    

def main():
    run = True

    player1 = pygame.Rect((40, 350), (PLAYERWIDTH, PLAYERHEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    start_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = 0

    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                break

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_w] and player1.y - PLAYERVELOCIT  >= 0:
            player1.y -= PLAYERVELOCIT
        if keys[pygame.K_s] and player1.y + PLAYERVELOCIT + player1.height <= HEIGHT:
            player1.y += PLAYERVELOCIT

        bgdisplay(player1, elapsed_time)
    pygame.quit()

#Filename Check
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've tried using the freetype library but without success, any tips on how to fix the issue?

Answer (score -1):

You were pretty close!

In `def bgdisplay(player1, elapsed_time)`, you need to be sure that you are updating `pygame.display.update()` your display *after* everything you need to draw has been rendered, one way or another.

```py
def bgdisplay(player1, elapsed_time):
    WIN.blit(BG, (0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, "white", player1)
    time_text = FONTE.render(f"Time: {round(elapsed_time)}s", True, "white")
    WIN.blit(time_text, (100, 10))
    pygame.display.update() # <- This was moved to the bottom of the fn
```